# Distribution of Sensor Uncertaintiy/Error in Datasheets

Tags: sensor, measurement

In a typical sensor datasheet, there is a range of uncertainty for a given parameter. For example, there are min, typ and max values for the sensor sensitivity. In general, the datasheets do not provide information on how these values are obtained. Are these errors/uncertainties **normally** or **uniformly** distributed over the lower and upper bounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are these errors/uncertainties normally or uniformly distributed over the lower and upper bounds?

In most cases it's more complicated than that. Tolerances are often due to changes or drifts in manufacturing processes, parameters, temperature & humidity, operator, plant, machines, etc. or material properties. Within a given batch (parts manufactured during the same shift with the same materials on the same machine) the overall range will typically much smaller than the stated tolerance, but it's not necessarily centered around the mid point. Parts from a different day, plant, process, etc. may create a badge that's also fairly tight but around a different mid point.

The mid points tend to drift over time and occasionally jump. Drifting is a normal fact of life. Once it starts affecting the yield, the manufacturing process will be adjusted to bring it back into the center. Jumps also happen if there is a new machine, a new batch of raw materials, change in process or environmental conditions, etc.

So the actual distribution that you see will depend a lot on how you select your samples (source, data range, etc) and what the underlying manufacturing processes are. It's not going to be uniform and it's rarely a Gaussian.

Comment: If you buy a quartz oscillator with ±20 ppm frequency tolerance, you get a mostly deterministic error that changes with ambient temperature but never exceeds ±20 ppm in the allowed temperature range. It's a deterministic dependency on environmental parameters, not a random process. There are also manufacturing tolerances and ageing, but for a quartz it's the deterministic temperature dependency that defines the error bounds. Any attempt to reason about probability distributions is futile.

Comment: However purchasing lots(>100) of parts [is going to exhibit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) a normal distribution. To some degree.

Comment: @Vorac. Sure, but the normal distribution you get today will be different than from the one you will get when you buy next Wednesday. Mean and std dev do drift